# Suggestions on tracking open source project usage

Tags: measurement

I have a small open source project, hosted on Google Code, and I'd like to be able to get a sense as to where and how the project is being used (besides the visitor info I can get from Google Analytics, and the download counts).

As it is open source and does not contain any 'powered by' or tracking code, I realize this is pretty much impossible, so I am trying to figure out how to have the user's of the project volunteer this information. All I can think of off of the top of my head is:

- Starting a discussion thread that people could post links to the sites they've used the code on.

Any suggestions as to the best way to get any insight into this?

Comment: Closed this question as per the site scope changes discussed on [meta]. This question doesn't relate to project management as described in the [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net)?  It will gather certain statistics about your project, including downloads and allow users to indicate if they "use" your project or not.  Might be part of what you are looking for anyway.